# Laravel Elequent Query whereJsonContains not work on utf8 and persian characters

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, mariadb

I used 
Laravel Elequent Query `whereJsonContains()` , but not work on utf8 and persian characters.

Can anyone help me?

**Edited**:

json like this:

books: `"[\"نهنگ\",\"vel\",\"eos\"]"`

Comment: Post a sample JSON data with the persian characters

Comment: @CaddyDZ , i edit question!

Comment: Those characters should have no problem with JSON and MySQL.  Are you saying `whereJsonContains` is having trouble?  Or something else?  Keep in mind that Persian is written RTL; see if writing LTR will make it work.

Comment: @RickJames yes. for exp. it's return items if i input "vel" . but if i input  "نهنگ"  return nothing.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: If you have any idea please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

try like these

```php
    $json = json_decode("[\"نهنگ\",\"vel\",\"eos\"]");

    $header = array (
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'charset' => 'utf-8'
    );

    return response()->json($json , 200, $header, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: thank for your answer, but i said whereJsonContains() not work. that's mean, no resulr returned .